# Is it alright to thank my Master's thesis advisor, via e-mail, for getting a good grade?

Tags: thesis, masters, advisor

So, I received the grade for my Master's thesis over the weekend. I defended my thesis late September, and received my grade yesterday (due to university rules). I waited about 4 months to receive my grade, and it was well worth the wait.

So I was wondering if it's alright to shoot my professor and advisor a thank you e-mail? I am very happy with my grade, but I was wondering if it's a weird/improper thing to do to thank a professor for a grade they've given. Does anyone have any experience with this? I would greatly appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: Were you guys close throughout your writing of the thesis?  If yes, I think it's better to thank the professor in person and maybe go into some details about what you're thankful for, eg, key learning moments that your advisor provided you.  If you guys weren't that close, a thank you email is fine but still go into some detail about what you're thankful for, so that you're not thanking her for a grade, which would sound like you didn't earn your grade...

Comment: We were not that close, but yes I plan to thank her for her guidance. I've learnt a lot while writing up my thesis, so I will make sure to thank her for her guidance and the terrific learning experience. Plus, I waited for 4 months to receive my grade through official university communication, so I merely want to express my gratitude.

Also, I am no longer in the same country of my professor, so e-mail is the only way for me. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: No you shouldn't thank for your grade. Thank her for your help!

Comment: What subject? Maths?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of thanking her for your grade, I would thank her for the time and energy they spent with you during your thesis, as well as what she has taught you. You earned your grade, she did not hand it to you.